# Order of published/subscribed messages

Tags: ros, messages, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have a single publisher and a single subscriber. The publisher is publishing at short intervals.
Is there ensured that the messages arrive in order or do i have to care about it myself?
Is there an option to force sending in order?

Thanks!
Jonas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46713/order-of-published/subscribed-messages/) by [Jonas Koenemann](https://answers.ros.org/users/2587/jonas-koenemann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a single publisher single subscriber system they should all be ordered, but not guaranteed to all be there depending on your queue size.  If you have multiple publishers the should be relative ordering from the individual publisher, but no guarantees between two publishers on ordering.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since traffic is exchanged using (persistent) TCP channels (might not be true for all) messages arrive in order by *nature*.
You can also add a Header in the message type which contains a sequence number in order to prove this fact although not necessary.

---

Originally posted by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) with karma: 237 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2